# shortcode execution when the page is opened

Tags: jquery, javascript

Is it possible to have a link to a page in my website trigger a shortcode button without leaving the home page!

I have a shortcode button that activates the ordering process for the customer but I need to use this button a lot throughout my page and it's not WooCommerce related.

I want to create a link that I can refer to anywhere on my website that would trigger the shortcode button as soon as it's clicked.

Comment: Was it bethought with no page refresh or reload? if so, it happens on the browser side and does not require WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

No, shortcodes do not work this way as they are parsed on the server-side and replaced with the relevant content before the page is sent over to the visitor's browser.

What you could do is to place the shortcode within a hidden element (like a `<div>`), then have JavaScript/jQuery unhide the hidden element's content when a button is clicked.